# Experiment combination table around one point

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I am trying to solve a Problem with the `itertools` module in Python.
Unfortunately I couldn't solve it and I am looking for help here

Imagine we want to make a experiment, and we have 4 diffrent factors named:

```
[a,b,c,d]
```

Each of the factors can be changed around 3 different values for example:

```
a=[a1=10,a2=20,a3=30]
```

Now to see what the impact of the changed factor is I want only to change one value by one.

How can I get a list of all possible combinations?

So for this small example I am searching to create the following table:

```
    [[a1,b1,c1,d1]
     [a1,b1,c1,d2]
     [a1,b1,c1,d3]
     [a1,b1,c1,d4]
     [a1,b1,c2,d1]
     [a1,b1,c3,d1]
     [a1,b1,c4,d1]
     [a1,b2,c1,d1]
     [a1,b3,c1,d1]
     [a1,b4,c1,d1]
     [a2,b1,c1,d1]
     [a3,b1,c1,d1]
                 ]
```

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list

Comment: No, @ForceBru, neither of those are duplicates.

Comment: why don't you have  `[a1,b1,c2,d2]`?? how exactly are you choosing your combinations?

Comment: The solution of @kaya3 was exactly what i searcht for.. only thought there is already a tool like Itertools for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't need itertools; just use a nested loop. The outer loop selects which factor to vary, and the inner loop varies it over its possible values. The input format is a list of lists, where each "row" contains the possible values for one factor, the first value being its "default".

```py
def vary_individual_factors(factors):
    r = [f[0] for f in factors]
    yield tuple(r)
    for i, [first, *rest] in enumerate(factors):
        for x in rest:
            r[i] = x
            yield tuple(r)
        r[i] = first
```

Example:

```py
>>> factors = [
...     ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
...     ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'],
...     ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'],
...     ['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4']
... ]
... 
>>> for t in vary_individual_factors(factors):
...     print(t)
... 
('a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1')
('a2', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1')
('a3', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1')
('a4', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1')
('a1', 'b2', 'c1', 'd1')
('a1', 'b3', 'c1', 'd1')
('a1', 'b4', 'c1', 'd1')
('a1', 'b1', 'c2', 'd1')
('a1', 'b1', 'c3', 'd1')
('a1', 'b1', 'c4', 'd1')
('a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd2')
('a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd3')
('a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd4')
```

Comment: Thank you @kaya3!  This works very well, works perfect for my problem! 
Really thought before I am on a good way with the itertools model but seems like not..
Thanks a lot!